# unaligned memory access ARM assembly program

Tags: assembly, memory, arm, memory-alignment

I am doing a project in which I need to change my memory in order to turn off a hex display. However i am running into issues regarding doing unaligned accesses which is breaking my code and I don't get where exactly the problem is.

```
.global _start

.equ HEX0, 0xff200032
.equ HEX1, 0xff200033
.equ HEX2, 0xff200020
.equ HEX3, 0xff200021
.equ HEX4, 0xff200022
.equ HEX5, 0xff200023

.equ off, 0b00000000

_start:

    mov r0, #10         //HEX1 and HEX3
    bl HEX_clear_ASM
    
    b _stop

HEX_clear_ASM:
    push {LR}
    
    ldr r1, =off // loading the bits needed to turn off, am i allowed? just '00' hex
    
    //---------------clear-one-by-one-----------------//
    
    TST r0, #1      //if bit =1 --> flag = 0
    ldrne r2, =HEX0 //put adress of hex display in r2
    strne r1, [r2] //turn off
    mov r0, r0, LSR #1  //prepare the next bit
    
    TST r0, #1
    ldrne r2, =HEX1 //put adress of hex display in r2
    strne r1, [r2] //turn off --> code breaks here
    mov r0, r0, LSR #1
    
    TST r0, #1
    ldrne r2, =HEX2 //put adress of hex display in r2
    strne r1, [r2] //turn off
    mov r0, r0, LSR #1
    
    TST r0, #1
    ldrne r2, =HEX3 //put adress of hex display in r2
    strne r1, [r2] //turn off
    mov r0, r0, LSR #1
    
    TST r0, #1
    ldrne r2, =HEX4 //put adress of hex display in r2
    strne r1, [r2] //turn off
    mov r0, r0, LSR #1
    
    TST r0, #1
    ldrne r2, =HEX5 //put adress of hex display in r2
    strne r1, [r2] //turn off

    //----------------------------------------------//
    
    pop {PC}



_stop:
    b _stop
```

The simulator gives a breakpoint where i indicated it in my code, when trying to store the 4 bytes in an unlined area, i tried using `strbne` instead of `strne` but it says that it does not exists. It seems I either have to have the condition flag but store 4 bytes or store one byte but no conditions...

Comment: There are many versions of the ARM instruction set.
Conditional execution is partly or completely removed in some of the newer versions.

Comment: @TimmyBrolin: If you mean Thumb, you just need an `it` instruction.  This is clearly 32-bit code, not AArch64 (which did remove predication).  Probably the issue is that some assemblers need the condition before the `b` suffix for byte load/store.  like `strneb` instead of the `strbne` you'd expect.

Comment: @PeterCordes True.